# Write function to multiply matrices in C++

Tags: c++, matrix

As an exercise I am supposed to write a function that can multiply two matrices given that you specify a certain input. The way the exercise is written the function should be of the form:

```
void Multiply(double **res, double **A, double **B, int ARows, int ACols, int BRows, int BCols);
```

Where the result of the multiplication is written to res.
I am not sure I understand the above form. As far as I can understand it takes as input the addresses of two matrices and the number of their columns and rows. But what should the input of res be (which is the result of multiplying the matrices)? Should it be the address of a preallocated matrix with the correct dimensions? In that case I wrote the following to test the function (I also specified matrix A and B):

```
double** C;
C = new double [rows];
for (int i=0; i<rows; i++)
{
C[i] = new double [cols];
}
std::cout << Multiply(&C,&A,&B,Arows,Acols,Brows,Bcols) << "\n";
}
```

But I don't think that is correct. Here is my code for multiply:

```
void Multiply(double **res, double **A, double **B, int ARows, int     ACols, int BRows, int BCols)
{
    assert(ACols=BRows);
    for (int k=0; k<BCols; k++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<ARows; j++)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<ACols; i++)
            {
                res[j][k] += A[j][i]*B[i][k];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test for Multiply:

```
int main()
{
    int ARows = 2;
    int ACols = 3;
    int BRows = 3;
    int BCols = 2;
    int cols = ARows;
    int rows = BCols;
    double** A;
    A = new double* [ARows];
    for (int i=0; i<ARows; i++)
    {
        A[i] = new double [ACols];
    }
    double** B;
    B = new double* [BRows];
    for (int i=0; i<BRows; i++)
    {
        B[i] = new double [BCols];
    }
    A[0][0]=1;
    A[0][1]=2;
    A[0][2]=3;
    A[1][0]=4;
    A[1][1]=6;
    A[1][2]=10;
    B[0][0]=1;
    B[0][1]=2;
    B[1][0]=4;
    B[1][1]=6;
    B[2][0]=13;
    B[2][1]=9;
    double** C;
    C = new double* [rows];
    for (int i=0; i<rows; i++)
    {
        C[i] = new double [cols];
    }
    std::cout << Multiply(C,A,B,ARows,ACols,BRows,BCols) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: As Multiply expects a `double **` for `res`, and as `C` is already a `double **`, there's no need to pass `&C` to the function. Passing plain `C` is enough. Furthermore, as it's a already pointer, the function will be able to fill the pointed content.

Answer (score 3):

Doing `&C, &A, &B` will give the address that the double pointer pointer is stored at. This would mean that `Multiply` would take `double***`: a pointer to a `double**` type. You can just pass it as

```
std::cout << Multiply(C,A,B,Arows,Acols,Brows,Bcols) << "\n";
```

Which will pass three `double**` types, namely `A`, `B`, and `C`.

Also, the way you use `new` for C is incorrect. You need to use

```
C = new double*[rows];
```

You're also trying to print a void function, which isn't going to work. Multiply is not something you can print, you need to call it so that `C` is defined. Then you need to loop through and output `C` manually. I have written code below.

```
#include <iostream>

void Multiply(double **res, double **A, double **B, int aRows, int aCols, int bRows, int bCols)
{
    if (aCols != bRows)
        return;

    for (int i = 0; i < aRows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < bCols; j++)
        {
            res[i][j] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < aCols; k++)
            {
                res[i][j] += A[i][k]*B[k][j];
            }
        }
    }   
}

void Initialise(double **res, int rows, int cols)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {   
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            res[i][j] = i*j; // whatever you want.
        }
    }   
}

int main()
{
    int aRows = 10; 
    int aCols = 5;
    int bRows = 5;
    int bCols = 6;

    double** A = new double*[aRows];
    for (int i = 0; i < aRows; i++)
    {   
        A[i] = new double[aCols];
    }   

    double** B = new double*[bRows];
    for (int i = 0; i < bRows; i++)
    {   
        B[i] = new double[bCols];
    }   

    Initialise(A, aRows, aCols);
    Initialise(B, bRows, bCols);

    double** C;
    C = new double*[aRows];
    for (int i = 0; i < aRows; i++)
    {   
        C[i] = new double [bCols];
    }   

    Multiply(C,A,B,aRows,aCols,bRows,bCols);

    for (int i = 0; i < aRows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < bCols; j++)
        {
            std::cout << C[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: These are using dynamic memory though, so not necessary to pass by reference.

Comment: I have tried to define Multiply below but I am not sure how I should call A and B. Since they are now double pointers can I simply write A[i][j] or should I write **A[i][j]? I get some weird errors when trying to compile. I have included my code for Multiply in the OP.

Comment: Need to use C = new double*[rows];

Comment: Sorry, found more errors haha. You cannot use std::cout on a void function, it just doesn't make sense. When you call Multiply(), you will then need to use std::cout on each element of C, as shown in the code.

Comment: You should click the tick for the right answer. Looking at your profile, you haven't accepted any answers for the questions you've asked. And you keep deleting your comments.